# How to find the Vue component that I want to pass information to?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, architecture, vuejs2

I'm looking for advice in architecting my Vue app. There's a map with stuff you can click on, and a sidepanel that shows information about what you clicked on. The side panel is wrapped in a `new Vue(...)` (I'm not sure what to call that - a Vue object?) Currently I attach every Vue object to `window` so I do stuff like (simplified):

```
map.on('click', e => window.sidepanel.thingName = e.feature.thingName);
```

Now, the sidepanel code and the map code are in different modules that otherwise have little reason to communicate.

My approach seems to work ok, but I just wonder what some better patterns would be, other than using globals.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Vue()` => called a vue instance (aka vm)

I think what you are doing is reasonable if you are working inside of constraints.  There are a few alternatives

1. Create an event bus (which is itself a vue instance) that you can use to manage the shared events.  Benefits here are that you don't have to reach into the components as deeply, but you also add complexity. https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/
2. Have you considered rending this as a page with the 2 vue instances as components inside of a parent?  That would allow you to have the parent take care of the state and pass it down to the components.  I think the main benefit of this approach is that it will be more simple to add additional functionality.

Both of these, you would end up doing something like this in the map

`map.on('click', e => emit('mapClick', e.feature));`

Then in your component listen for the mapClick either on the event bus if you go route 1, or in the parent container component if you go route 2

Hope that helps, good luck!

---

Example of Parent, the sidepanel would emit

```
sidepanel = Vue.component('sidepanel')
map = Vue.component('map')

parentComponent = Vue.component('parent', {
  components: { map, sidepanel },
  template: `
    <div>
      <map @mapClick="handleMapClick" :dataAsProp="someData"></map>
      <sidepanel @userClicked="handleUserClick" :dataAsProp="someData"/>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return { someData: [] }
  },
  methods: {
    handleMapClick(event, data) {
      // handle your update here, save data, etc
    },
    handleUserClick(event, data) {
      // handle your update here, save data, etc
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean by a "parent" exactly in this context?

Comment: Updated example, hope that helps